# Laravel file validation is not allowing anything through

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Frustrating one here: I am validating a file upload in my Laravel application, and here is my line that is throwing errors (I literally copy-pasted this off of StackOverflow and double checked that it was right on the Laravel docs):

```
'video_file' => 'mimetypes:video/avi,video/mpeg,video/quicktime'
```

Now, what you're probably thinking is, "Ok, so are you uploading one of those types? Are you SURE?".

Yup.

I took the validation run off, uploaded the same video file, and ran this code to check what the MIME type was:

```
$files = $request->file('video_file');
foreach($files as $file) {
   file_get_contents($file);
   return $file->getMimeType();
}
```

Wanna know what it returned?

```
video/quicktime
```

So, how should I validate that someone is uploading a video file? To be honest, at this point, I really have no need to validate each video type, I just need to make sure it is A VIDEO. Doesn't matter if it is .mov, .mp4, .avi, whatever.

Keep in mind this is a 'multiple' input for the file upload, so while that may have something to do with it, I don't think so because I took that off and it still didn't go through.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When validating arrays you are better of with [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays).

For example:

```
'video_files' => 'array',
'video_files.*' => 'mimetypes:video/avi,video/mpeg,video/quicktime',
```

As you can see I would also suggest using a plural key when handeling an array, but that is personal taste.

Comment: Won't lie, I have NO clue why that worked, but it did! Sometimes, thats all that matters for the moment. Haha thanks so much!